# NoReverseMatch at /theme/ Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['theme/(?P<article1_id>[0-9]+)$'

Tags: django

I have the following views

```
def article1(request, article1_id):
    article1 = get_object_or_404(Presse, pk=article1_id)
    context = {
      'article1': article1,
    }
    return render(request, 'article/article1.html', context)
```

The following urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.theme, name='theme'),
    path('<int:article1_id>', views.article1, name='article'),
]
```

but get error when trying to pass parameter on my templates url

`<h4 class="uk-margin-top"><a href="{% url 'article' article1.id %}">{{entreprenariat.titre}}</a></h4>`

Comment: hope someone could help me . struggling to find where the issues is . use django 3.0.5

Comment: can you tell template name where these lines exist? `<h4 class="uk-margin-top"><a href="{% url 'article' article1.id %}">{{entreprenariat.titre}}</a></h4>` and show it's view?

Comment: the template name is `article1.html ` and the i show the views in my question

Comment: You have a logic error in your code. I suggest you to take some tutorial before trying to make an app yourself.

Comment: I think my code is right I even took a tutorial and a github project that worked but when I try with my project I got this error